# Measurable asumption

Tags: measure-theory

Theorem 11.8 (i) page 94 in [Measures, Integrals and Martingales](http://books.google.dk/books?id=_OjSIphIrH0C&lpg=PP1&hl=da&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false) makes the assumption that the function $u:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

I suppose they mean $\mathcal{B}\cap[a,b]/\mathcal{B}$ measurable. **Is this correct?**

Comment: yes, it is usually meant Borel measurable.

Comment: Can you write remark 11.10?